# Prometheus listening different ports at same time

Tags: prometheus, wmi-service

I am trying to listen 2 ports at same time ports are:
http://localhost:9182/metrics
http://localhost:8080/prometheus
Can anyone suggest a good way?

Comment: Could you give more information I.e are those Prometheus ports you are trying to expose, are you trying to scrape both those endpoints etc

Comment: 9182 is wmi exporter for monitoring my windows machine 8080 is Spring Boot program shows some Counters and Gouges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following [Prometheus config file](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/):

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: job1
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - localhost:9182
  - job_name: job2
    metrics_path: /prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - localhost:8080
```

Since the targets use different metrics paths (`/metrics` vs. `/prometheus`), they must be defined in separate jobs. `/metrics` is the default metrics path, so you don't need to configure it in `job1`, but you need to configure `/prometheus` as the metrics path in `job2`.